# Why does a fixed random seed have no effects for a tensorflow function that has no parameters?

Tags: tensorflow, random-seed

I am fixing a global random seed with tensorflow, and trying to use @tf.function so that each function call can behave the same at each call. Tested on functions `f` and `g` below:

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)


@tf.function
def g(i):
  print ("round", i)
  return tf.random.uniform([1])


@tf.function
def f():
  return tf.random.uniform([1])


print(g(0))

print(g(1))

print (f())

print (f())
```

While I did get different results on calling `g`, I got different results on calling `f`. Why?

```
round 0
tf.Tensor([0.13047123], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
round 1
tf.Tensor([0.13047123], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.5380393], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.3253647], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue from tensorflow and its discussed in detail here- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33297

Tensorflow guide recommends not to use `tf.normal.` functions as well: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers [image]

You should use `tf.random.stateless_uniform([1], seed=(2,3))` instead of `tf.random.uniform([1])`

Comment: The question is not about what should be used, you are not answering the question.

Comment: The answer to the above question is, its a bug in `tensorflow`. This is a known issue discussed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33297. That's why the guide says ` use of tf.random.normal is discouraged'

Comment: Then explain that in your answer, don't just give the "solution" without any context, specially if the question ask why.

Comment: While this is not a direct answer, I have learned the problem is due to a tensorflow defect. Thanks.